# Unable to load Revit API in a project targeting .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-framework-version, revit-api, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to use xUnitRevitUtils.2020 package which has a dependency on ModPlus.Revit.API.2020. My project target framework is .Net Standard 2.0. I receive the following warning:
[image]

and when I try to run the application I get the following exception:
[image]

and the application crashes. Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried just uninstalling and reinstalling the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the RevitAPI.dll reference to your project from Revit folder.
see: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/simplecontent/content/lesson-1-the-basic-plug.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use it outside Revit - not as a Revit plugin. but recently got to know that it is not possible. Thanks for your answer